# Webextension thunderbird get attachment

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on, thunderbird, thunderbird-webextensions

First of all I want to apologize if this question may seem too simple but I haven't found any solution since yesterday and I'm not very good at javascript.
I want to create a personal Thunderbird addons that will communicate with an application I have created, for that I need to have a file attached in a message. I used these commands

```
    console.log("attachment : " + test);
    var test1 = await browser.compose.listAttachments(tab.id);
    console.log("attachments : " + test1.toString());
```

to learn the language a bit better and see what was returned and the return message is:
`TypeError: browser.compose.ComposeAttachment is undefined`

And listAttachments does not return anything

Complete code :

```
browser.composeAction.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {

    var file = new File(["foo"], "foo.pdf", {
        type: "application/pdf",
    });

    console.log("File : " + file);

    browser.compose.addAttachment(tab.id, {
        file
    })

    var test = await browser.compose.ComposeAttachment.getFile();
    console.log("attachment : " + test);

    var test1 = await browser.compose.listAttachments(tab.id);
    console.log("attachments : " + test1.toString());

 
});
```

Thanks to the research I did, I correctly configured the manifest.json with the compose permission.
I would like to know if someone can explain to me how to use these functions in this context.

Best regards